# Unable get access to code tab in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: permissions, msdn, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am getting the below error:

[image]

> We could not verify your Visual Studio subscription so we’ve downgraded you to Stakeholder. Please visit our troubleshooting page for more details then click here to Retry

is what the error message I am getting,
and when I check the users list, I am getting below message:

[image]

I am clueless on how to get the access to the code.

Comment: Please put the error & message inside the question (not as images) and describe what have you tried so far (code, example, etc.)

Comment: We could not verify your Visual Studio subscription so we’ve downgraded you to Stakeholder. Please visit our troubleshooting page for more details then click here to Retry is what the error message  I am getting

Answer (score 4):

You need to connect your MSDN subscription to the account that you use for connecting to Visual Studio Team Services. You do this by visiting https://my.visualstudio.com/subscriptions (previously http://www.msdn.com) and following the steps to activate your subscription.

Otherwise VSTS cannot determine if you have a valid license, and hence the message downgrade you to *Stakeholder*, a license type that does not allow you to view code.

Comment: in the new portal can you provide me the steps to add my subscription bcz in new portal under subscriptions there is no option to add my subscription

Comment: and in https://msdn.microsoft.com/subscriptions/manage i can see iwas having enterprise subscription but when i go to subscriptions in new portal i cannot see my subscriptions

Comment: @SivaTejaDonthukurthi: Under *Related Links* you will find an action *Activate Retail Subscription* where you can enter the activation key you received through mail.